# Autocomplete only saves data from first AJAX form submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have a simple form and I want to give an user the ability to select previously posted data using `autocomplete="on"`. I am submitting form with AJAX. I am using `Google Chrome 87.0.4280.88 64 bit`. Here is the code that I have:

```html
<form action="/Debug" method="POST" id="myForm">
    Brand: <input type="text" name="brand" autocomplete="on" /><br />
    Model: <input type="text" name="model" autocomplete="on" /><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Debug',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('data', data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**LIVE DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/jcuzfo69/

When I submit the form for the first time, posted data is saved and displayed in autocomplete dropdown. But, when I enter new data and submit the form again, data is not saved by the browser.

Data for first submit:

[image]

Autocomplete after first submit:

[image]

Data for second submit:

[image]

Autocomplete after second submit:

[image]

I would expect to see *Volkswagen* listed as a brand after second submit has ocurred. Why is it not saved by the browser?

Comment: Not sure, what happens on your side, but it works well https://prnt.sc/wdnfq6

Comment: Can you post a link to code snippet instead of picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using run snipets button:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Debug',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('data', data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/Debug" method="POST" id="myForm">
    Brand: <input type="text" name="brand" autocomplete="on" /><br />
    Model: <input type="text" name="model" autocomplete="on" /><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried my scenario with your snippet as well - only data from the first submit is saved.

Comment: Could it be browser-related? Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: I am using the exact same version but it doesn't work for me. But it works in Firefox.

Comment: Not sure, why it not shown other submitted values in autocomplete. it's weird. might be cache or something, you may give a try after cleaning it all. hope this will work